# Undefined webix tree table when trying to load array of JSON

Tags: json, webix, webix-treetable

```
var tree = webix.ui({
  view: "tree",
  url: "my_python_func()"
});
```

I am using this and my data is coming from a python file (i mean `url:"my_python_func()"`).

The python func is returning an array of JSON. When I use that in the tree, it shows the value as undefined. Can someone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can get json array using ajax, and assign it to js object. And instead of writing
 `url: "my_python_func()"`, you can just type `data: jsobject`